# Not able to run Python inside HTA

Tags: python, hta

I have a Python script which I would like to run from a HTA. However, I was not able to get this to work. Here is my HTA code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <HTA:APLICATION>
    <title>Python Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script language =python src = "t.pys"></script>
    <form><button onclick = "d1()">c</button></form>
</body>    
</html>
```

And here is my Python code:

```
def d1():
    alert("A")
```

When I try to run it and press the button, I get this error message:

> the value of the property d1 is null or undefined

I'm using Active Python 3.6, I already `pip-installed PyWin32` and registered Python with `C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\win32comext\axscript\client\pyscript.py`. 
I also tried with regular Python 3.6 doing the same process with no success.

Also, I tried changing the `language =python` with `language = "python"` and `language = "Python"`, and using a `.py` file, but I got the same result.

I was able to run a simple "Hello World" by running `CScript.exe script.pys`. The Python script I want to run would be really hard to translate into JScript, as it uses functions not present in this language.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/7644962/18771 (especially the comment under the answer)?